# Credenciales en el gestor de repositorios de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]alguien ha usado el gestor de repositorios de Visual Studio?
lo comencé a usar, y cuando creo un repositorio permite generar una clave, la genero, luego cuando hago un clone o un primer pull nunca me pide esa credencial, entonces:
-Son públicos estos repositorios
-Son privados pero falta configurar algo?

Gracias

Comment: Lucho y donde se encuentran esos repositorios? tienes un servidor o se encuentran en github, bitbucket, etc...Agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, y se especifico para que pueda ser contestada fácilmente, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Podes hacerte una cuenta de Visual Studio Team Services, y tenes un servidor de repositorios al estilo github, gitlab, etc.
El tema es que he leido que es gratuito y privado, pero no logro que pida credenciales en ningún momento.